# docusaurus: how to use ifm-color-primary in styles.module.css

Tags: html, css, styling, docusaurus

The scaffolding of Docusaurus creates the following in `custom.css`

```
:root {
  --ifm-color-primary: #25c2a0;
  --ifm-color-primary-dark: rgb(33, 175, 144);
  --ifm-color-primary-darker: rgb(31, 165, 136);
  --ifm-color-primary-darkest: rgb(26, 136, 112);
  --ifm-color-primary-light: rgb(70, 203, 174);
  --ifm-color-primary-lighter: rgb(102, 212, 189);
  --ifm-color-primary-lightest: rgb(146, 224, 208);
  --ifm-code-font-size: 95%;
}
```

and the following in `styles.module.css`:

```
.features {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I want to define `.featuresAlt` as the following:

```
.featuresAlt {
  background-color: lightest;
}
```

and then use it in `index.js`; something like:

```
{features && features.length > 0 && (
  <section className={classnames(styles.features, styles.featuresAlt)}>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        {features.map((props, idx) => (
          <Feature key={idx} {...props} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
)}
```

My questions are:

- I am trying to separate different sections (e.g., `features` and `products`) with different background colors, should I be defining my own style, or there something built-in?
- The above-defined `featuresAlt` is incorrect as it will not have the `lightest` background; how can I fix it?
- Is it recommended to define colors for styles in `styles.module.css` or they should be defined in a different place?

(I went over [styling page of Docusaurus documentation](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/styling-layout), but could not find the info I need.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```css
background-color: var(--ifm-color-primary-lightest)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it exactly how you would use it in normal CSS:

```css
.featuresAlt {
  background-color: var(--ifm-color-primary-lightest);
}
```